# ./configure not present in node.js tar

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

I'm following a Node.js tutorial for compiling Node from Source with NPM. The issue is that while previous builds contain the configure script, the most recent tar, 6.9.2, does not but that's a part of the steps required for compiling from source. If I download an older version like 0.1.5, the configure script is there. The tutorial requests I do a ./configure but there's nothing resembling configure after I unzip 6.9.2. Here's the tutorial I'm following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-compile-node-js-with-npm-from-source-on-centos-6

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the source from
https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2.tar.gz the configure script should be there.

Also, see the github page for node.js:
https://github.com/nodejs/node
where configure script is present.

I guess you downloaded it from elsewhere? Nevertheless, here is the standard build procedure for Node:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have CentOS 6.x, and have enabled the EPEL repository, you can use yum to install node/npm:

```
$ sudo yum install npm
```